# Revert back to older GitHub browser editor

Tags: github, browser, editor

I do a lot of coding at work on my mobile using the GitHub browser editor.

[image]

A few days ago I was promoted to switch to a new version when I clicked to edit a file.

The new editor is awful, I won't go into why, unless users want to know.
I've browsed through what I believe to be all the account and project settings but haven't found a way to revert to the older editor.

If anyone knows of a way to revert to the older editor, please, for the love of God, let me know.